# Get specifik value from array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I dont think I understand this with arrays. I have tried several methods that I found here. But I can't make it work. I understand there is a ton of this question, but I would really appreciate your help.

Can someone please help me? I want to get the URL to the image [Image] only.

Json looks like this:

{"authResponse":{"Success":true,"ErrorMessage":null},"apiCallResponse":{"Success":true,"StatusMessage":"Sign initiated","Response":{"OrderRef":"de666ed7-77ce-4da0-77a8-7777776b914b","AutoStartToken":"77cb86b3-7771-77ba-8b68-5c52e229effd","Image":"https://www.testsite.com/moretests/2f7f9152-7775-4554-7779-777777eadda"}}}

Array looks like this:

Array ( [authResponse] => Array ( [Success] => 1 [ErrorMessage] => ) [apiCallResponse] => Array ( [Success] => 1 [StatusMessage] => Sign initiated [Response] => Array ( [OrderRef] => de666ed7-77ce-4da0-77a8-7777776b914b [AutoStartToken] => 77cb86b3-7771-77ba-8b68-5c52e229effd [Image] => https://www.testsite.com/moretests/2f7f9152-7775-4554-7779-777777eadda ) ) )

Code I have tried:

```
$json = json_decode($response, true);
print_r($json);
echo "<br />Test: <b>".$array[4]['Image']."</b>";

//

print_r($json['Image']);

//

foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    echo "Key: $key, value: $value";
}

//

$index = 2;
$elem = array_slice($json, $index, 1, true);
$key = key($elem);
$value = reset($elem);
echo "Key: $key, value: $value";

//

$stringItem = $json['Image'];
echo "An item by key 'Image': {$stringItem}\n";

//

if(array_key_exists("Image", $values)) {
    echo 'We have an image.';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After decoding that json you will get something called [multidimensional array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing). That means that value of some key in array can be another array. So you need to follow keys in each inner array to get to `Image` key.

In your example you need to do something like this:

```php
$image = $json['apiCallResponse']['Response']['Image']
```